# C++ string uses maximum buffer allocated?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I declare a variable `string s;`

and do `s = "abc";` now it has buffer of 3 characters.

After

`s = "abcd"` it has a buffer of 4 characters.

Now after the third statement

`s = "ab"` question is will it keep the buffer of 4 characters or will it reallocate a 2 character buffer?

If it will allocate 2 character buffer is there any way I can tell it to keep the allocated maximum buffer.

So does it keep the buffer of maximum size ever allocated ?

```
s = "ab"
s="abc"
s="a"
s="abcd"
s="b"
```

Now it should keep a buffer of size 4.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> s = "ab" question is will it keep buffer of 4 words or will it
>   reallocate 2 word buffer ?

It will not reallocate the buffer. I don't know if it's mentioned in the standard, but all the implementations I have ever seen issue a reallocation only if they need to ***increase*** the capacity. Never to decrease. Even if you have a string with 4 characters and call `.resize(2)` or `.reserve(2)` the capacity will not change. In order to force the string (or containers) to reallocate memory to fit the exact size, there's a simple `swap` trick for that

```
s.swap(string(s));
```

What happens here? You create a temporary from s which will have its capacity exactly equal to `s.size()` then swap it with your original string. The destructor of the temporary will free all the necessary resources.

Again, I am not claiming this is standard, but all the implementations I've seen have this behavior.

Comment: It depends on the implementation: g++ will change capacity if you assign a new string to it, with a smaller capacity, and VC++ will usually use the smallest capacity it can from a fixed set of capacities.  (I suspect you're thinking of `std::vector`; what you describe is the behavior of neither g++ nor VC++, and I can't believe you've seen neither of those.)

Answer (score 10):

The string will keep its buffer once it is allocated, and only reallocate if its needs an even larger buffer. It will also likely start with an initial buffer size larger than 3 or 4.

You can check the allocated size using the `capacity()` member function.

---

After James' comments below I still believe my answer is correct for the examples given in the question.

However, for a reference counted implementation a sequence like this

```
s = "some rather long string...";

std::string t = "b";
s = t;
```

would set `s.capacity()` to be equal to `t.capacity()` if the implementation decides to share the internal buffer between `s` and `t`.

Comment: Well, `size()` is the number of characters in the string. It will keep its buffer `capacity()` even when assigned a smaller string.

Comment: This is very implementation dependent, and what is described corresponds neither to the behavior of VC++ nor of g++.

Comment: it's exactly how VC++ implements `std::string`, at least VC2008. initial buffer size is 15 and is doubled every time larger buffer is required.

Comment: @Andy At least in VC++ 2005, the buffer size isn't doubled; it grows by some other multiple (1.5?).  But it's true that it doesn't seem to reduce the buffer size very often.  (g++ uses a completely different strategy.)

Comment: @James: how differently? can you provide more details please? I would be very surprised to see any implementation that reduces buffer size w/o special trick like `string.swap(std::string())`, because I very often rely on this for memalloc optimization purposes. BTH, I was sure it's required by standard.

Comment: The standard says that if you have called `reserve()` it cannot reduce the buffer. I don't know any implementation that keeps track of this, so they just don't reduce `capacity()` (unless swapped or something).

Comment: @Bo I'm not sure about that (and it's certainly not the case for the g++ implementation).  All I can find in the standard is that (immediately) after calling `reserve()`, `capacity()` is >= the value.  And the standard definitely says it's a "hint"; you don't have nearly the guarantees you have for the other containers.  The standard explicitly says that the rules are formulated to allow reference counting, which is what g++ does, and reference counting almost requires reducing the capacity in an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see the behavior of your implementation by calling
`std::string::capacity` at various times.  In general, I'd be surprised
if any implementation ever had a buffer of three characters.  (Not
words, but bytes, at least on most modern machines.)  In practice,
implementations vary, and also vary depending on how the new length
comes about: with g++, for example, removing characters with
`std::string::erase` will not reduce the capacity of the string, but
assigning a new, smaller string will.  VC++ doesn't reduce the capacity
in either case.  (In general, VC++ and g++ have very different
strategies with regards to memory management in strings.)

EDIT:

Given the other responses (which don't even correspond to usual
practice): here's the small test program I used to verify my statements
above (although I really didn't need it for g++—I know the
internals of the implementation quite well):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename Traits>
void
test()
{
    std::string s;
    size_t lastSeen = -1;
    std::cout << Traits::name() << ": Ascending:" << std::endl;
    while ( s.size() < 150 ) {
        if ( s.capacity() != lastSeen ) {
            std::cout << "  " << std::setw( 3 ) << s.size()
                << ": " << std::setw( 3 ) << s.capacity() << std::endl;
            lastSeen = s.capacity();
        }
        Traits::grow( s );
    }
    std::cout << Traits::name() << ": Descending: " << std::endl;
    while ( s.size() != 0 ) {
        Traits::shrink( s );
        if ( s.capacity() != lastSeen ) {
            std::cout << "  " << std::setw( 3 ) << s.size()
                << ": " << std::setw( 3 ) << s.capacity() << std::endl;
            lastSeen = s.capacity();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Final: capacity = " << s.capacity() << std::endl;
}

struct Append
{
    static void grow( std::string& s )
    {
        s += 'x';
    }
    static void shrink( std::string& s )
    {
        s.erase( s.end() - 1 );
    }
    static std::string name()
    {
        return "Append";
    }
};

struct Assign
{
    static void grow( std::string& s )
    {
        s = std::string( s.size() + 1, 'x' );
    }
    static void shrink( std::string& s )
    {
        s = std::string( s.size() - 1, 'x' );
    }
    static std::string name()
    {
        return "Assign";
    }
};

int
main()
{
    test<Append>();
    test<Assign>();
    return 0;
}
```

Try it.  The results are quite instructive.